# mDNSResponder Errors on iOS

Tags: ios, networking, dns, testflight

I'm seeing some weird stuff happening in my app.  After coming back to the app from suspended state, at seemingly random times, network actions all hang.  They don't timeout or call back and error, they just hang.  I captured the log, and the last time it happened, these two lines were logged just after the first request was sent off.

```
mDNSResponder[45] <Error>:  14: Could not write data to client because of error - aborting connection
mDNSResponder[45] <Error>:  14: DNSServiceGetAddrInfo v4v660b818f4fdfde88126fa9675dc82b6ad252e09c3.sdk.testflightapp.com.
```

Looks like it could be something related to having TestFlight in my app, or maybe it's just issues with DNS.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TestFlight 0.8.3 is buggy and I ended up fixing this by removing the TestFlight SDK.